# How to convert strings into an existing variable names

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, tuples

Is it possible to convert a tuple strings into variable names? As an example, here is part of my code

```py
Subjects = ["01","02","03","04"]
S01_squat = data["S01"][13:425]
S02_squat = data["S02"][320:680]
S04_squat = data["S03"][0:500]
S05_squat = data["S04"][0:500]
columns_names = tuple(["S"+ i +"_squat" for i in Subjects])
print(columns_names)
```

This will show a tuple that contains all variables names in string format. My actually columns is more than this and I want to do the `pd.concat` using a robust method and to do so I need to extract the variables from their string names

```
squat_data = pd.concat(columns_names, axis=1)
```

this will output an error since `columns_name` is a tuple of strings.

As for now, and because of short in time I did the concate using:

```
squat_data = pd.DataFrame()
squat_data = pd.concat((squat_data,right_knee_data["S01"][13:425]), axis=1)
squat_data = pd.concat((squat_data,right_knee_data["S02"][320:680]), axis=1)
```

which is worked for me, but not answering the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just trying to fix the error you are getting -

```
tups = tuple(['A','B','C'])

pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(columns=[i]) for i in tups])
```

This would give you an empty data frame with columns A, B, C. You can do this even more simply by just `pd.DataFrame(columns=tups)`

---

If you do want a method to change string values to variable names, I would recommend using a dictionary.

```
my_dict = {}
tups = tuple(['A','B','C'])

for i in tups:
    my_dict[i] = 10 #some value(s)
    
my_dict['A']
```

```
10
```

This allows you to store `key, value pairs`, where the key can be the `'string'` and the value can be any data structure you want to store for it. When you want to fetch the value for the string, just use `my_dict['string']` instead.